# Getting a document of firestore using firebase-admin SDK [permissions error]

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I would like to get a document of the firestore via my application using the firebase-admin SDK.

It is able to do that on dev environment, but is not on stg environment.

The following error is output when the application on stg try to get a document.

```
Error: 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call.js:31:19)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:352:49)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client-interceptors.js:328:181)
    at /layers/google.nodejs.yarn/yarn_modules/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:188:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
```

My application is implemented using TypeScript and Express.
It is worked on the firebase functions.

I have checked firestore rules, firebase admin is initialized, firebase keys (fbProjectId,
fbPrivateKey, fbClientEmail) are set and dataset exists on firestore.
Firebase keys are got on firebase console.

Does anyone have any idea of solutions or a cause of the problem?

The script is as follows.

```typescript
import * as cors from "cors";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser";
import * as express from "express";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set("fbProjectId", process.env.FB_PROJECT_ID ?? "");
app.set("fbPrivateKey", process.env.FB_PRIVATE_KEY ?? "");
app.set("fbClientEmail", process.env.FB_CLIENT_EMAIL);
if (admin.apps.length === 0) {
  admin.initializeApp();
}
export const db = admin.firestore();

app.get("/objects/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  const object = await db.collection("objects").doc(id).get().then((doc) => {
    return doc.data();
  })
  res.status(200).send(object)
  return
});
```

Comment: What is your "stg environment"? (e.g. is it a GitHub actions workflow? A separate Firebase project? Emulated Cloud Function? Deployed Cloud Function?) This error would normally turn up if your Admin SDK hasn't been properly initialised with a valid service account credential.

Comment: I mean "stg environment" is a separate Firebase project and it works on deployed Cloud Function.
I checked `admin.apps.length` outputs `1`.
But, is there a possibility Andmin SDK hasn't been properly initialized?
Or are there any other cause?